# Hasura anonymus role permission, API not exposed

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker

I am using Hasura for a project. When I give permission for the public (API exposed for everybody), then no API is exposed in the `API` section of Hasura. In this case I only `X-Hasura-Role` `public` in headers.
[image]

But all APIs for role `public` are exposed when I add `x-hasura-admin-secret`. For the role `public`, `x-hasura-admin-secret` should not be needed. I don't understand what's wrong is doing there?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE` as `public` in `.env` environment. If you use Hasura cloud then add it `Hasura Env Vars` section.